How to derive this form of helicity spinor (massless/high energy limit)
Srednicki 50.7 says that in the massless limit, we can express $$u_-(\textbf{p})\bar{u}_-(\textbf{p}) = \begin{pmatrix} 0&-p_{a\dot{a}}\\0&0\end{pmatrix}$$
This  comes from a previously derived equation
$$u_-(\textbf{p})\bar{u}_-(\textbf{p}) = \frac{1}{2}(1+s\gamma_5)(-\not p+m)$$
where we set $m=0$. However, he then says

On the other hand, we know the two lower components of it banish, so $$u_-(\textbf{p}) = \begin{pmatrix} \varphi_a\\0 \end{pmatrix}$$

How would one derive that the last two entries of $u$ are $0$? My first thought was the dirac equation but I couldn't really take that anywhere.
Closely related but doesn't quite answer question

First there is an intuitive explaination, for Dirac fermions, the
mass term is
\begin{align*}
\left(i\partial_{\mu}\gamma^{\mu}-m\right)\Psi & =0\\
\Psi & =\begin{pmatrix}\psi_{L\alpha}\\
\psi_{R}^{\dot{\alpha}}
\end{pmatrix}
\end{align*}
Here using the Weyl basis, where the representation of lorentz group
is block diagonal, thus a Dirac spinor is a direct sum of two irreducible
representations, i.e. $V=V_{L}\oplus V_{R}$
\begin{align*}
\gamma^{\mu} & =\begin{bmatrix} & \sigma^{\mu}\\
\bar{\sigma}^{\mu}
\end{bmatrix}\\
\sigma^{\mu} & =(1,\sigma^{i})\\
\bar{\sigma}^{\mu} & =(1,-\sigma^{i})
\end{align*}
Then Dirac equation
\begin{align*}
\begin{bmatrix}-m & i\partial_{\mu}\sigma^{\mu}\\
i\partial_{\mu}\bar{\sigma}^{\mu} & -m
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}\psi_{L}\\
\psi_{R}
\end{bmatrix} & =0
\end{align*}
the matrix is mixing the first two components and last two components
so the solution $u(p,\sigma)$ is a linear combination of $V_{L}$
vector and a $V_{R}$ vector, however in $m=0$ case,
\begin{align*}
\begin{bmatrix}0 & i\partial_{\mu}\sigma^{\mu}\\
i\partial_{\mu}\bar{\sigma}^{\mu} & 0
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}\psi_{L}\\
\psi_{R}
\end{bmatrix} & =0
\end{align*}
The equation decouples, thus one can choose a solution with only non-zero
$\psi_{L}$ or $\psi_{R}$ . this only explain why we CAN choose a
spinor with last two component zero. but not explain why we choose
it. 
To explain we first need to relate the particle helicity to the transform of field, which can be obtained by rotate a field at $x=0$.
\begin{align*}
\Psi(x) & =\int\frac{d^{3}p}{(2\pi)^{3}}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2E_{p}}}\sum_{\sigma}u(p,\sigma)b(p,\sigma)e^{-ipx}+\sum_{\sigma}v(p,\sigma)c^{\dagger}(p,\sigma)e^{ipx}\\{}
[J_{3},\Psi(0)] & =\int\frac{d^{3}p}{(2\pi)^{3}}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2E_{p}}}\sum_{\sigma}u(p,\sigma)[J_{3},b(p,\sigma)]+\sum_{\sigma}v(p,\sigma)[J_{3},c^{\dagger}(p,\sigma)]\\
U(\Lambda)\Psi(0)U(\Lambda)^{-1} & =\Lambda_{1/2}^{-1}\Psi(0)\\
(1-i\theta J_{3})\Psi(0)(1+i\theta J_{3}) & =\Psi(0)-i\theta[J_{3},\Psi(0)]=(1+i\theta S^{12})\Psi(0)\\{}
[J_{3},\Psi(0)] & =-S^{12}\Psi(0)\\
S^{12} & =\frac{i}{4}\left[\gamma^{\mu},\gamma^{\nu}\right]=\frac{1}{2}\begin{bmatrix}\sigma^{3} & 0\\
0 & \sigma^{3}
\end{bmatrix}\\{}
[J_{3},b(k,\sigma)] & =-\sigma b(k,\sigma)
\end{align*}
The last identity is only true when $k=(E,0,0,E)$, a rotation operator
can transform an annihilation operator in generic momentum into another
momentum.
\begin{align*}
 & \int\frac{d^{3}p}{(2\pi)^{3}}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2E_{p}}}\sum_{\sigma}\frac{1}{2}\begin{bmatrix}\sigma^{3} & 0\\
0 & \sigma^{3}
\end{bmatrix}u(p,\sigma)b(p,\sigma)+\sum_{\sigma}\frac{1}{2}\begin{bmatrix}\sigma^{3} & 0\\
0 & \sigma^{3}
\end{bmatrix}v(p,\sigma)c^{\dagger}(p,\sigma)\\
=&\int\frac{d^{3}p}{(2\pi)^{3}}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2E_{p}}}\sum_{\sigma}u(p,\sigma)[J_{3},b(p,\sigma)]+\sum_{\sigma}v(p,\sigma)[J_{3},c^{\dagger}(p,\sigma)]
\end{align*}
Since operators of different 3-momentum are linear independent, in specific,
the equation for $p=k$ mode annihilators:
\begin{align*}
\sum_{\sigma}\frac{1}{2}\begin{bmatrix}\sigma^{3} & 0\\
0 & \sigma^{3}
\end{bmatrix}u(k,\sigma)b(k,\sigma) & =\sum_{\sigma}u(k,\sigma)[J_{3},b(k,\sigma)]\\
\sum_{\sigma}\frac{1}{2}\begin{bmatrix}\sigma^{3} & 0\\
0 & \sigma^{3}
\end{bmatrix}u(k,\sigma)b(k,\sigma) & =\sum_{\sigma}\left(-\sigma\right)u(k,\sigma)b(k,\sigma)\\
\frac{1}{2}\begin{bmatrix}\sigma^{3} & 0\\
0 & \sigma^{3}
\end{bmatrix}u(k,\sigma) & =\left(-\sigma\right)u(k,\sigma)\\
\end{align*}
because $\vec{k}=k_{z}$, $h=\frac{\vec{S}\cdot\vec{k}}{|k|}=S_{z}=\sigma$,
thus:
\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{2}\begin{bmatrix}\sigma^{3} & 0\\
0 & \sigma^{3}
\end{bmatrix}u(k,h) & =\left(-h\right)u(k,h)
\end{align*}
now solve Dirac equation
\begin{align*}
\begin{bmatrix}0 & i\partial_{\mu}\sigma^{\mu}\\
i\partial_{\mu}\bar{\sigma}^{\mu} & 0
\end{bmatrix}u(k,h)e^{-ikx} & =0
\end{align*}
\begin{align*}
\begin{bmatrix}0 & k_{\mu}\sigma^{\mu}\\
k_{\mu}\bar{\sigma}^{\mu} & 0
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}u_{L}\\
u_{R}
\end{bmatrix} & =0\\
\begin{bmatrix}u_{L}\\
u_{R}
\end{bmatrix} & =\beta\begin{bmatrix}1\\
0\\
0\\
0
\end{bmatrix}+\alpha\begin{bmatrix}0\\
0\\
0\\
1
\end{bmatrix}
\end{align*}
As promised, the basis can be chosen as one in $V_L$ one in $V_R$, and using the relation we got:
\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{2}\begin{bmatrix}\sigma^{3} & 0\\
0 & \sigma^{3}
\end{bmatrix}u(k,h) & =\left(-h\right)u(k,h)\\
u(k,\frac{1}{2}) & =\begin{bmatrix}0\\
0\\
0\\
1
\end{bmatrix}\\
u(k,-\frac{1}{2}) & =\begin{bmatrix}1\\
0\\
0\\
0
\end{bmatrix}
\end{align*}
The negative helicity state must associated with the solution with last two entries zero.
For an arbitary momentum, one need to act a representation matrix
of rotation and boost on both functions , note that the We are in
Weyl basis, the representation of lorentz group is block diagonal,
to be specific, the infinitesimal transformation is
\begin{align*}
S^{\mu\nu} & =\frac{i}{4}\begin{bmatrix}\sigma^{\mu}\bar{\sigma}^{\nu}-\sigma^{\nu}\bar{\sigma}^{\mu}\\
 & \bar{\sigma}^{\mu}\sigma^{\nu}-\bar{\sigma}^{\nu}\sigma^{\mu}
\end{bmatrix}\\
u(p,-\frac{1}{2}) & =\exp(-\frac{i}{2}\omega_{\mu\nu}S^{\mu\nu})u(k,-\frac{1}{2})
\end{align*}
Which gives a vector only in $V_L$.
Conversely if the theory has only left handed fermion, at high energy, it must have only helicity $-1/2$ particle (and a helicity $1/2$ anti-particle from $c^\dagger(p,\sigma)$ operator which I didn't derived)
